# Using the || operator in the a return value of a function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I am trying to understand this example in chapter 3 of the http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html free online book. I am confused about the use of || operator in the return function of the final else in a if statement.

Here is the code

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target){
      console.log("-------ifBlock-------");
      console.log("startInteger = " + start + " == targetInteger = " + target + " historyString " + history); 
      return history;
    }
    else if (start > target){
      console.log("-------elseIfBlock-------");
      console.log("startInteger = " + start + " > targetInteger = " + target + " historyString " + history); 
      return null;
    }
    else{
      console.log("-------elseBlock-------");
      console.log("startInteger = " + start + " historyString = " + history);
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

findSolution(24);
```

Here is all the console.logs I have been getting to try and understand the flow of the return || operator.

```
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 1 historyString = 1
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 6 historyString = (1 + 5)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 11 historyString = ((1 + 5) + 5)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 16 historyString = (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 21 historyString = ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 26 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 63 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 48 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 33 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = (((1 + 5) + 5) * 3)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 18 historyString = ((1 + 5) * 3)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 23 historyString = (((1 + 5) * 3) + 5)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 28 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) + 5)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 69 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) * 3)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 54 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = (((1 + 5) * 3) * 3)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 3 historyString = (1 * 3)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 8 historyString = ((1 * 3) + 5)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 13 historyString = (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 18 historyString = ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5)
-------elseBlock-------
startInteger = 23 historyString = (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 28 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 69 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 54 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3)
-------elseIfBlock-------
startInteger = 39 > targetInteger = 24 historyString = ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) * 3)
-------ifBlock-------
startInteger = 24 == targetInteger = 24 historyString = (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

Where I get lost is right where the `else if (start > target){}` block starts. When that code gets executed it is then asked to return null. And at that point the `historyString = (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5)`.

**My Questions is what creates the jump to the other part of the elseBlocks return statement the * 3 after the || instead of the + 5. Is it because the previous return was null. Or is it because start is now > than the target.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's because *elseIfBlock* always returns null, so `null || func()` causes a call to `func()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is a [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). This means that it will return the first expression if it can be converted to true; otherwise, it returns the second expression.

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.
>
> <sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation))</sup>

So in the following snippet, if the first `find()` doesn't evaluate to a truthy value, then it will execute and return the second `find()`.

```
return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
       find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

Comment: ok so lets say it runs `find(6 , "( 1 +5 )")` on the second pass after the first `find(1, "1")` what about this second pass is true. I hope I am not confusing you. I just don't see why it is true vs false.

Comment: Is it because it does not `return null`

Comment: The second pass doesn't have to be true. Only the first pass has to be true to be returned. If you think about it like human speech it is saying "Return this thing if it's true, otherwise return this other thing whether it is true or not." I hope I'm understanding what you're asking correctly.

Comment: I think so. Basically the first `find()` function call is used unless something !true is returned, like null and then the other `||` `find()` function is run.